# Pass a parameter to another page with rewriting

Tags: next.js13

I want to pass a parameter from one page to another page, without it being displayed in the url.

I use "Link" with "as" to rewrite the url, and I cannot get the parameter with useSearchParams.

It only works if I remove the "as".

Here is the code:

```
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function CoreCard({ groupName, vmName, vmId }) {
    return (
        <Link href={{pathname: vmName, query: {vmID: vmId}}} as={"/vmconfig"} className="p-2 w-full" >
            <p className="font-light">{ groupName }</p>
        </Link>
    )
}
```

```
'use client'
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'

export default function VmConfig() {
        const searchParams = useSearchParams()
        console.log(searchParams.get('vmID'))

        return (
         <></>
    )
}
```

Is it possible to get the parameter while retaining the rewrite?

Thanks.